# Can't open a new activity on the method onResponse of Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm developing a basic Android login application, I have watched and read a lot of YouTube tutorials and now I am confused with my code (since I am not a pro).

When I type the wrong password, the application will toast the message as expected but it shows nothing when I type the correct password according to my database record. I have no idea how to fix it.

I have tried to replace the code "Intent intent..." with another toast message, in order to see if something will come out when I enter the correct password, but nothing shows even for toast message.

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
        if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {
            SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                    .userLogin(
                            obj.getString("username"),
                            obj.getString("email")
                    );

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    obj.getString("message"),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It should start the HomeActiviy when both username and password are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your startActivity from the main thread, I believe...

```
          public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                    if(!obj.getBoolean("error")){
                        SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                                .userLogin(
                                        obj.getString("username"),
                                        obj.getString("email")
                                );

                        myActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                           @Override
                           public void run() {
                           //Your code to run in GUI thread here
                           }//public void run() {
                              Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
                              HomeActivity.class);
                              startActivity(intent)
                           });
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                obj.getString("message"),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: I think that's not the problem, as you can read in the question the Toast shows if the password is wrong.

Comment: I have tried this solution as well but it said that "Non-static method runOnUiThread cannot be referenced from a static context. Agh android seems a bit complicated to me

Comment: Have you checked the content of JSONObject obj to verify the value of the 'error' boolean is indeed false?

Comment: I dunno, actually I follow the approach from this youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKtWV5htt_M but i cant get the same result, really confused

Comment: On the Non-static method runOnUiThread message, have you tried it without the myActivity. ?  Just plain runOnUiThread(new Runnable()... that's what I use.  What kind of class is this running in?  An Activity, Fragment, something else?

Comment: Just a normal class called "LoginActivity.java", I tried it without the "myActivity." after that, it underlines the startActivity(intent) instead.  Dunno how to correct it

Comment: Does LoginActivity.java 'extend' Activity?  If not, that is a poor choice for a naming convention, as LoginActivity would make it sound like an Activity object.  If it does not extend the Activity class, then you need a reference to the Activity that spawned the LoginActivity class, which was likely an activity.  That's what the myActivity  reference was in my code. You would use that before runOnUiThread as well as startActivity.

Comment: No, it does not extend any other activity, so now I need to create another empty activity call myactivity? sorry I am really new to programming I can't really understand what I have to do next in order to make my application work

Comment: No worries, in general, an Android has a 'main' activity, which is the Activity that gets launched when the app first starts up.  9 times out of 10 it is actually named MainActivity.java (but doesn't have to be).  It will 'extend' the Activity class, which means it inherits everything from the Activity class, and adds on to it. You do this in the class declaration:  public class MainActivity extends Activity... {  Typically, if a Main Activity needs to force a user to Login, they will create an Intent based on the LoginActivity.java class file (and that class file would also extend Activity).

Comment: The Main Activity would then start that Intent by doing the startActivity(loginIntent) which would open your LoginActivity as a real valid Activity object.  It is the Activity object that has the built in methods runOnUiThread() and startActivity().  So, if you make all of your classes extend Activity, those classes will automatically get those methods.  If you are not extending Activity anywhere, I don't know how you are getting anything to appear on the screen at all, as Activity is how almost all screens are created.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is in `getApplicationContext()`.

Try this solution

1. In the method of this volley request add a context parameter

   ```
   Context context
   ```
2. Start activity like this

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
   context.startActivity(intent);
   ```
3. Set the context as `this` when you call your volley function

Comment: Ahh sorry, I don't quite understand what I have to do on step 3, could you please explain more, thank you very much.

Comment: When you call the request function in your activity, you have to set the context variable . Let's assume your function signature is like this `public void myRequest(Context context, String  name, ......)` . So in your activity you call this function like this `myRequest(this, "xxxxx", ....)`

Comment: Actually, I used PHP to connect to mysql, is it possible that something went wrong with my php script, therefore, i cant oepn a new activity in android.